# required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-autoconfiguration

Recently we upgraded spring-boot version to 2.7.2 and spring framework version to 5.3.22. Since then we are seeing this error in one of the apps

"required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' that could not be found."

Spring documentation says that if there is a dependency called micrometer-registry-<?> then it will autowire the required MeterRegistry. We do have that dependency in out project. But it is not happening.

We do have the following properties in application.yml. But actuator is also not working

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      statsd:
        enabled: true
        flavor: datadog
        host: localhost
        port: 8125
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  metrics:
    enabled: true
```

Can some one please tell me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 11):

You need `spring-boot-starter-actuator` on your classpath.

Comment: I already have it as a dependency. But it still is not working.

Comment: It might not be on your classpath (in your jar, etc.)

Comment: It is there. I double checked. Anyway we had downgrade the spring framework to make this work

Comment: Helped for me to see the `traceId` and `correlationId`: `2022-12-25T02:12:13.991+03:00  INFO [Sender,63a7874db0f29789c75af5dda9c24af4,c75af5dda9c24af4] `

Comment: Note that it must be `spring-boot-starter-actuator` (as the answer points out), and not `spring-boot-actuator`, which looks really similar, but will leave you scratching your head for a good while.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your configuration, because of double "management.metrics". Move metrics.enabled in the first block.